# Como separar diferentes valores de um foreach

Tags: php

Estou usando uma função em PHP para extrair as cores principais de uma imagem que encontrei em uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3468588/9537649) bem antiga na SO.

Como eu separo os valores que são listados dentro do foreach?

Quando são listados não da para determina onde eles tem que aparecer, a função apenas gera uma lista com todas as cores, na função tem como determina a quantidade mas não tem como especificar onde cada cor tem que aparecer.

Eu quero aplicar cada cor em um local especifico.

Exemplo:

Eu vou consulta duas cores apenas, para exibir assim:

```
echo "<div style='width:20px;height:20px;background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #$color1 40%, #$color2 100%)'></div>";
```

No exemplo acima eu mostro a primeira cor no $color1, a segunda no $color2

Função:

```
<?php 

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/3468588/9537649

function colorPalette($imageFile, $numColors, $granularity = 5) { 
   $granularity = max(1, abs((int)$granularity)); 
   $colors = array(); 
   $size = @getimagesize($imageFile); 
   if($size === false) 
   { 
      user_error("Unable to get image size data"); 
      return false; 
   } 
   // Carrega somente imagens jpg
   //$img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
   // Carrega 'qualquer' tipo de imagem
   $img = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imageFile)); 

   if(!$img) 
   { 
      user_error("Unable to open image file"); 
      return false; 
   } 
   for($x = 0; $x < $size[0]; $x += $granularity) 
   { 
      for($y = 0; $y < $size[1]; $y += $granularity) 
      { 
         $thisColor = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y); 
         $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $thisColor); 
         $red = round(round(($rgb['red'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
         $green = round(round(($rgb['green'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
         $blue = round(round(($rgb['blue'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
         $thisRGB = sprintf('%02X%02X%02X', $red, $green, $blue); 
         if(array_key_exists($thisRGB, $colors)) 
         { 
            $colors[$thisRGB]++; 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            $colors[$thisRGB] = 1; 
         } 
      } 
   } 
   arsort($colors); 
   return array_slice(array_keys($colors), 0, $numColors); 
} 

// sample usage: 
$palette = colorPalette('image.jpg', 2 /* 2 e quantidade de cores */ , 4 /* o 4 não sei bem o que e mas acredito que seja a precisão das cores*/); 

foreach($palette as $color) {
    // As cores são listadas com o $color
    echo "<div style='width:20px;height:20px;background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #$color 40%, #$color 100%)'></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$palette` nada mais é do que um array, portanto pode acessar cada elemento utilizando a sintaxe `array[chave]`

> `$palette[0]`, `$palette[1]`, etc.....

Para `$palette = colorPalette('image.jpg', 2, 4);`

faça assim

```
echo "<div style='width:20px;height:20px;background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #$palette[0] 40%, #$palette[1] 100%)'></div>";
```

**Caso haja mais cores, ex: 6**

```
$palette = colorPalette('image.jpg', 6, 4);
```

**pode variar a combinação**

```
echo "<div style='width:20px;height:20px;background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #$palette[0] 40%, #$palette[3] 100%)'></div>";
```

**ou**

```
echo "<div style='width:20px;height:20px;background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #$palette[2] 40%, #$palette[4] 100%)'></div>";
```

Comment: nossa, tão simples e eu quebrando a cabeça kkk, muito obrigado.